# how to execute two table column data in a single function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have to calcuate BMI for a user by taking Users_height & users_weight from the different two tables.

Here is the two tables(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQs4.gif) & (https://i.stack.imgur.com/liqhH.gif)

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
  weight_pounds    height_cm 
     121.25           130
     132.28           160
     154.32           221
     176.37           434
```

user_weight  Table
[image]

user_height table
[image]

I tried this function, but its showing error:

```
 function get_all_user_bmi($uid) 
{ 
    $this->load->database(); 
    $this->db->select('w.weight_pounds','h.height_cm');
    $res = $this->db->order_by('w.uweight_id', 'ASC')->order_by('h.height_id', 'ASC')
            ->get_where('user_weight w',array('w.creater_id'=>$uid))
            ->get_where('user_height h',array('w.creater_id'=>$uid))
            ;
    $ret = array();

    foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
        $weight=$row['w.weight_pounds']* 4.88;
        $height=($row['h.height_cm']*0.032808)*($row['h.height_cm']*0.032808);  
        $bmi=$weight/$height;
        $ret[] = $bmi;  //final bmi formuala calculated
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Error is:

```
 A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'h.height_id' in 'order clause'

SELECT `w`.`weight_pounds` FROM (`user_weight` w) WHERE `w`.`creater_id` = '3235' ORDER BY `w`.`uweight_id` ASC, `h`.`height_id` ASC

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\webapp\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Hope someone can help me here...

**UPDATE**

Added extra column `same_id` in both the column to meet the requirements and added `$this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.same_id = h.same_id');`    this piece of code, now its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `join` you haven't joined your tables, if you need the user details like height , weight etc then in your tables you should save the user information along with the user id in both tables  as there is one - to- relation , then join your tables on the basis of that user id to calculate the bmi for user

```
$this->db->select('w.weight_pounds, h.height_cm');
$res = $this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.user_id= h.user_id')
         ->order_by('w.uweight_id', 'ASC')->order_by('h.height_id', 'ASC')
        ->get_where('user_weight w',array('w.creater_id'=>$uid));
```

OR

```
$this->db->select('w.weight_pounds, h.height_cm');
$this->db->from('user_weight w');
$this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.user_id= h.user_id')
$this->db->where('w.creater_id',$uid); 
$this->db->where('h.creater_id',$uid); 
$this->db->order_by('w.uweight_id', 'ASC')->order_by('h.height_id', 'ASC')
$query = $this->db->get();
```

And in loop just use the column name

```
foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
        $weight=$row['weight_pounds']* 4.88;
        $height=($row['height_cm']*0.032808)*($row['height_cm']*0.032808);  
        $bmi=$weight/$height;
        $ret[] = $bmi;  //final bmi formuala calculated
    }
```

[**Reference Active record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: Sorry, its not complete answer,    The creater_id is the id of users creater_id,so all this data is created by the same users, hence `The join column is full of duplicates.`  .Here is the two tables(http://i.stack.imgur.com/eOQs4.gif) & (http://i.stack.imgur.com/liqhH.gif)

Comment: @user2732367 so where is the user id in these tables how you can relate the height and weight of single user in these tables ??

Comment: `user_id` is the foreign key in the above 2 tables, and primary key in the `userdetails` table

Comment: Now i solved my problem. i have added a new field in the both table `same_id` and replaced this line of (`$this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.creater_id = h.creater_id')`)your code with `$this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.same_id = h.same_id');` this code. Now its working fine.  I request you to specify this things in your answer and also make some changes in your answer so that i can accept it as correct answer.

Comment: As you have posted the query so i guess `creater_id`  exists in both tables so i assume its the user id so i have provided the join example now if you have added the `same_id` to relate then its good :)

Comment: kindly update your answer with `same_id` and also specify `add extra column in both table` . May be this answer  can help other users in future

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately That does not look good,  Here i answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/18806347/2732367

Comment: Okay, do you know the reason, why someone down-vote? Actually person,who down-vote the question,they should write the reason too..

Comment: Yes downvoter should have to leave a comment to make better or what problem he/she sees

Comment: yeah that only i am saying, but there is not any comment from the person who down vote this question....

Answer (score 0):

With reference to @dianuj Answer, and my little effort and searched ,  i found out a solution :

To distinguish between two table i  use an extra column same_id of every same input . like

```
ON  w.same_id = h.same_id
```

Finally my code looks like below, and solved my problem

```
$this->load->database(); 
$this->db->select('w.weight_pounds, h.height_cm'); 
$this->db->from('user_weight w','user_height h');
$this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.same_id = h.same_id');
$this->db->where('w.creater_id',$uid); 
$this->db->where('h.creater_id',$uid); 
$this->db->group_by('w.weight_pounds');
$this->db->order_by('w.uweight_id', 'ASC')->order_by('h.height_id', 'ASC');  
$res = $this->db->get(); 
$ret = array(); 
foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
    $weight=$row['weight_pounds']* 4.88;
    $height=($row['height_cm']*0.032808)*($row['height_cm']*0.032808);  
    $bmi=$weight/$height;
    $ret[] = $bmi;  //final bmi formuala calculated

}
```