# unable to combine two tables to get the correct output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to combine two tables and get the result as shown in below, but currently i am not getting output as i desired

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
  weight_pounds    height_cm 
     121.25           130
     132.28           160
     154.32           221
     176.37           434
```

I have two tables and on each table there is a foreign_key column `creater_id`

**user_weight  Table**
[image]

**user_height table**
[image]

I tried this function, but its showing a wrong output:

```
function get_all_user_bmi($uid) 
{ 
  $this->load->database(); 
  $this->db->select('w.weight_pounds, h.height_cm');
  $this->db->from('user_weight w');
  $this->db->join('user_height h' ,'w.creater_id = h.creater_id');
  $this->db->where('w.creater_id',$uid); 
  $this->db->where('h.creater_id',$uid); 

  $this->db->group_by(array('h.height_id')); 
  $this->db->order_by('w.uweight_id', 'ASC')->order_by('h.height_id', 'ASC'); 
   //$this->db->group_by('h.height_id','w.uweight_id'); 
  $this->db->distinct();
  $res = $this->db->get(); 
    $ret = array(); 
     foreach ($res->result_array() as $row) {
    $weight=$row['weight_pounds']* 4.88;
    $height=($row['height_cm']*0.032808)*($row['height_cm']*0.032808);  
    $bmi=$weight/$height;
    $ret[] = $bmi;  //final bmi formuala calculated

}
 print($this->db->last_query());
    return $ret;
}
```

Getting different Output(not correct) by executing this above php code

[image]

Comment: Why are you storing the weight and height in separate tables?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Could be an application that tracks the users weight and height over time.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Actually i have developed this functionality for my Fitness websapp, here i am storing users height & weight in separate table because daily user have to update their height or weight and after getting all these data i can calculate user BMI.

Comment: @JustinWood yeah you are right?  Daily user can update their height & weight , and based on the data i am showing them their respective graph for the each day, and also if users already updated their `height` and `weight` for today date then it will fire update query or else it will fire INSERT query in the respective table

Comment: @user2732367 peoples' height change over time?  Or this is for children/adolescents?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It may be , if a adolescents stared using my Fitness Webapp and after few months/year if he increases his height then it is effective.  SO that i can show them their accurate BMI,

Comment: You cant join because the creater_ids are all the same.Also duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803990/unable-to-implement-group-by-on-multiple-table-column

Comment: @Mihai i did not get correct answer there after a prolong wait , so i thought to ask it again here. Also i may delete this question , just reading the suggestions in this comment

Comment: @user2732367 The answer is correct,if you don't want do do anything about it is your choice.

Comment: @Mihai just reading the suggestion ,afterwards i will delete this question. May be i have to take out some other solution. May be i will put these two tables column in a single table

Comment: @user2732367 Look I told you what is wrong.You can post this question as many times as you like I don't care.I wont intervene any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37393/discussion-between-user2732367-and-mihai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant join the two tables because all fields have same `creater_id` , so every weight can have any height.

you have four methods if you want solve it .

**1** -to distinguish between them you should use an extra column `same_id` of every same input . like

```
  ON  w.same_id = h.same_id
```

and then join the tables by this column . [HERE example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48273/1)

**2**- make uweight_id and height_id same and then join the tables by those two columns.

```
    ON w.uweight_id = h.height_id
```

**3**- this method i dont recommend it and i dont advice it because its not in all cases true when updating the table.  is to use `CROSS JOIN` .

**4**- make just one table with height and weight together and reach then by id (simpler).

Comment: i could not understand the 1 st option. Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: create column same_id in both tables and when creater add a wight and height you update this column by an id , so like this you can reach height and weight by this id.and then join the tables by this column its better solution.

Comment: Sorry stil i could not understand it 100%, can you please insert some data in the extra column `same_id` for the complete understanding.  Then i think i can understand..

Comment: yes you insert same values in that added column  in both tables .when creater added a data. next data you insert two same values for weight and height , then you can reach both weight and heigth by this same value.

Comment: thanks, now i will let you know once i applied and tested completely with my webapp... Thanks again.

Comment: Finally my Solved. And i am not sir, i am a collage student and a part time Web programmer. You must be Sir! You are so talented. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer,Actually i did not see that line. i deleted it because that was no useful to another users, same question exists here.

Comment: First i asked this one ->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803289/how-to-execute-two-table-column-data-in-a-single-function  then after not getting correct answer i asked here once again and you answered it correctly

Comment: ok :) and now whats the question ? this function you have is not same in any question you posted :) .

Comment: This only is the question and the previous one was the first question i asked. And other question i deleted because they were not so good and no useful for other users.